# Añadir objetos en directo escribiendo en Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

estoy intentando realizar una aplicación que lo que haga como añadir Divs hacia la izquierda a la vez escribiendo el nombre en Mysql. Lo estoy intentando con PHP y bootstrap pero se me antoja algo tosco con formularios. Pensé en hacerlo con Javascript pero no se por donde empezar. os dejo lo que llevo hecho para que podáis ver alguna idea.

```
<?php
 include("../resources/config.php");
 session_start();

 $_SESSION["id_table"] = $_GET["id_table"];

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $inputTable = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['inputName']);
  foo($inputTable);


 }


?>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>hola caracola</title>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body>
 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <?php
     function foo($nombre){
       ?>
       <div class="col-sm-3-12">
         <?php echo $nombre ?>
       </div>
       <?php
     }
      ?>
     <div class="col-sm-3-12">


     <form action="" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="inputTable">Nombre tabla:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTable" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Nombre tabla" name="inputName">
       </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

lo que he intentado es con un form añadir con echo un nuevo div por encima pero no realiza la idea que quiero. tambien pense en hacerlo con refresh cada vez que creas un nuevo div pero no se ve muy dinámico.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que se te antoja algo **tosco** con formularios?  ¿En qué entra aquí el uso de MySQL?

Comment: al crear una nueva lista por asi decirlo se deberia de guardar en la BBDD. el caso que eso lo se hacer lo que no me acaba de salir es la parte visual. Respecto a lo de se tosco con formularios es que se vería el corte del refresh al lanzar el form.

Comment: No tiene por que ocurrir un refresh al enviar el formulario, puedes usar Ajax para mandar los datos desde el formulario sin que se refresque la página, por eso me sonaba raro lo de *tosco*, pues los formularios son elementos que se usan de forma elegante para remitir datos al servidor. En cualquier caso, creo que deberías aclarar mejor la pregunta, porque es algo confusa.